# jqGrid: Restore FilterToolBar chosen values after destroyFilterToolBar

Tags: jqgrid

I`m trying to implement dynamic content of filter dropdowns, so in beforeRequest request I analyze filters value, prepare dropdown values and call updateDropdownValues:

```
var updateDropdownValues = function(dropdownValues){
    $("#securityJqGrid").jqGrid("destroyFilterToolbar");
    for(var columnName in dropdownValues) {
        $("#securityJqGrid").jqGrid("setColProp", columnName, {
            searchoptions: {value: dropdownValues[columnName]}
        });
    }
    $("#securityJqGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true});
    var postData = jQuery($("#securityJqGrid")).jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData");
    postData.filters = lastFilters;
}
```

The problem is that after filterToolbar creation it doesn`t restore value of previous filtering. If I choose value from another dropdown it will filter data only by this new value instead of combination of two values - new one and previous. Is there any way to restore filterToolbar state?